# How to profile code on R studio Server, if Profvis keeps crashing?

Tags: r, rstudio, profiling, rstudio-server

I am currently running some ML models on a R studio Server with 64gb of RAM,

My ML models are run relatively quickly and what one would normally expect given their sparse matrix size

the methods i have been using are Logistic regression and XGBOOST

However I now want to "profile" and see the memory being used at the actual model fitting stage - i have used Profvis, but it does not seem to work on my matrix of 760 variables by 228,000 rows on the rstudio server, it does not load the actual profvis viewer and uses up all 64GB of ram!

Is there any way around this? (aside from shrinking the data)

As in other packages aside from profvis, that allow you to profile code at any moment to see how much memory is being used?

Comment: Have you tried `help('Rprof')`?

Comment: yep - nothing on there that regards a solution and R prof does not say memory usage only time in MS which is 20 whereas profvis has 10ms and memory allocation and de allocation!

Comment: Sorry but `Rprof` does have a `memory.profiling` argument, defaulting to `FALSE`. try to set `memory.profiling = TRUE` and see if the result is what you want.

Comment: did not work and only gives total allocation - not allocation and deallocation at points

Comment: `profvis` is just a wrapper interface for `Rprof`. It uses `Rprof(prof_output, interval = 0.01, line.profiling = TRUE, gc.profiling = TRUE, memory.profiling = TRUE)`. So like this you can collect the same data and analyze it afterwards.